# My webpage is not working in my LAN

Tags: wordpress, http, dns, web-hosting, host

I bought a domain(travelarize.com) from GoDaddy and a host from HostGator. The problem is that, my domain does not work in my own network .It runs fine in other networks.If I am using a proxy in my web-browser, it runs on my network too, otherwise it gives the error:

> *This website is temporarily unavailable, please try again later.*

I am using WordPress for designing

[error that I receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXKeD.png)

Comment: When I try and lookup your domain I get nothing. `host travealarize.com
Host travealarize.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)` is that the correct spelling? its not showing as registered with whois either. That aside are you hosting the page? on your own network or externally?

Comment: Yes it is the correct domain

Comment: it's travelarize.com

Comment: that works - what IP address do you get when you ping it from the lan? `host travelarize.com
travelarize.com has address 103.50.162.127`

Comment: returning ip address is  184.168.221.25

Comment: I think the proxy service your using in the browser may be at fault. Have you done any dns updates recently or anything like that? what happens if you test with a dns server of 8.8.8.8

Comment: i have seen on my screen, "Error establishing a database connection". i think you have to update wp-config.php and apply proper credentails.